# Passing HTTP GET request with body using Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, http, elasticsearch, get

I'm trying to get an amount of docs in `elasticsearch` using a Ruby script. To do that, I need to pass a HTTP GET request with body and I seem to be stuck at this. I'm using `rest-client` gem as it seems to be the easiest.

Here's my code to get the amount of docs in entire `Elasticsearch` database:

```
url = 'http://localhost:9200/bookings/_count'
response = RestClient.get(url)
puts response
```

Now I need to pass the same request, but with this JSON, as body:

```
query: {
 filtered: {
  query: {
    term: { status: "book_confirmed" }
    },
     filter: {
      bool: {
       must: {
        range: { date_booked: { gte: "now-7d/d", lte: "now-7d", time_zone: "+2:00" } } },
       should: {
        term: {contract: "xd.hotels"} }
      }
     }
  }
```

}

How can I do this?

EDIT:

I've managed to achieve this with POST. When I was posting the question I was not aware, that `Elasticsearch` accepts POST requests in Count API.

Here's the code:

```
urlago = 'http://localhost:9200/bookings/_count'
responseago = RestClient.post(urlago, {query: { filtered: { query: { term: { status: "book_confirmed" } }, filter: { bool: { must: { range: { date_booked: { gte: "now-7d/d", lte: "now-7d", time_zone: "+2:00" } } }, should: { term: {contract: "xd.hotels"} } } } } } }.to_json, {content_type: :json, accept: :json})
puts 'Week ago:' 
puts responseago
```

Comment: How about using post instead?

Comment: Now that's a good question. To be honest, I was so focused on trying to do it with GET, I haven't even investigated to do it with POST. I'll do it right now.